# Was I rude to this potential employer?

Tags: job-search

I sent a CV to a HR consultant. 
she responded back with usual stock phrases like: 'We will keep you on file, blah blah blah'. 
I responded back with 'Noted, many thanks' the subject line.

I thought I was being professional but it turns out that noted basically means STFU!!

Is this true?

Edit: For reference this was the initial response from HR 'Hi Jacqueline, we still do not have any suitable positions at the current time. I thank you for your interest. We will be in touch if anything suitable materialises. Regards, Jane'

Comment: It's hard for us to guess exactly how a specific other person will interpret something, but as a hiring manager, I wouldn't have given your response a second thought. It would *certainly* not have struck me as "STFU."

Comment: Who told you it meant STFU ? Did the HR person answered back saying you were rude ?

Comment: it was one of my friends who said it meant STFU Assere. HR lady did not answer back but I was trying to build rapport with her for the future

Comment: Based on the message, it was a cold call type email, there likely wasn’t even a job.  Your friend is being over dramatic

Comment: Next time, parrot back that you'll keep an eye out for their concern, and act on it when you notice it becomes a problem.  I don't read your response as being overly rude, but is closes the topic too abruptly, with too much communication that you have discarded the person's input.  Instead accept the input, but opt to act upon it a a more opportune time (which may or may never come).

Answer (score 10):

It's perhaps a *little* brusque but "STFU" is probably a stretch (at least here in the UK), still given the fact that you've had a formulaic response that basically translates as "No" I don't think this is likely to have any real lasting consequences.